# AccuRev: How to "unkeep"

Tags: accurev

Neither Google nor the User CLI doc seem to be helpful.

I've "kept" some files and want to "unkeep" them.

I can see how to "unpromote" with "revert", but that does not seem to be the right command for just pitching the kept changes.  I'm sure it is one of the commands, but the command name choices (like verbing the noun, "defunct") leave me uncertain as to which might be the one I want.  So, which command has the option for unkeeping a kept file?  (A "see also" reference for the "keep" command would be nice, Micro Focus folks.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

"purge"  You'd think it means, "purge" from your work area or something, but it really means "purge the changes".  Too hard.

Comment: Syntax is `accurev purge <file>` And from `accurev help all` `PURGE

   undo all of a workspace's changes to an
   element
`

Who knew - @BruceK knew!